# Post more decimals than shown

Tags: javascript, html, post

I have a form where the user enter some value, I make some calculations using JS and return the result in a textbox that shows only two decimals to the user.

If he wants to save the result, he presses a submit button that will post the textbox value and save it in my database.

I would like to know if it's possible to show only two digits but post/store more (it reminds me Excel, where you see a limited number of decimals but somewhere it is stored a more precise value).

I thought about creating a hidden field with the full value that will be posted and stored instead, but I want know if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I was just going to suggest a hidden field, then you pre-empted me by mentioning that in your question. I would say that this is the best way of doing it. For bonus points, *don't* give the visible textbox a `name` attribute, so that it doesn't get sent to the server - saves a few bytes of bandwidth XD

Comment: Yes I would probably go with the hidden field. Keeps things quite simple and clean. You could replace the visible textbox with a `span` to avoid confusion with form fields, or Niets suggestion to not give it a `name` is good too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you store the not-rounded answer in the window object you can get it back any moment with javascript.

```
// ...
//calculating
// ...

var answer = 1 + 1;
window.answer = answer;

// Write answer to textbox in 2 decimals
theTextbox.value = Math.round(answer * 100) / 100;
```

Now you can store the value in the database using AJAX.

Using my this option the latest answer is always stored as:

```
window.answer;
```

Even after the function has run. It will stay there until the page is refreshed.

**Option 2**

Store the value in a hidden input field and wait until the user clicks the button to post the form.

```
// ...
//calculating
// ...

var answer = 1 + 1;

theHiddenInput.value=answer;

// Write answer to textbox in 2 decimals
theTextbox.value = Math.round(answer * 100) / 100;
```